# Facebook Messenger API: Webviews Opening in Browser

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I'm trying to use the Facebook Messenger API to create a "generic" message with a button.  When that button is clicked, I want to display a "webview" (ie. a framed version of a webpage inside Messenger).

However, even though my button has the required `webview_height_ratio` property, it still opens up in my phone's browser, not inside Messenger.  Since the Facebook documentation claims that that's all you need to make a button open a webview, I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong.

The message I'm sending to Facebook to create the button (as part of a generic template) is:

```
{
    "recipient":{
        "id": "some ID"
    },
    "message": {
        "attachment":{
            "payload":{
                "elements":[{
                    "buttons": [{
                        "title":"Webview example",
                        "type":"web_url",
                        "url":"http://www.example.com",
                        "webview_height_ratio":"compact"
                    }],
                    "image_url": "http://www.example.com/image.png",
                    "item_url": "http://www.example.com",
                    "subtitle":"It's a TV!",
                    "title":"Some TV"
                }],
                "template_type":"generic"
            },
            "type":"template"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if it was necessary, but I have white-listed the domain I'm trying to point to for the webview (but obviously that hasn't helped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was doing everything right: the problem was Facebook.  Evidently when you use a webview it *only* affects mobile users.  Web-based Messenger users get a new window regardless of whether or not you specify a `webview_height_ratio`.

Comment: This is outdated.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same issue.

In this Block

```
      "buttons": [{
                    "title":"Webview example",
                    "type":"web_url",
                    "url":"http://www.example.com",
                    "webview_height_ratio":"compact"
                }],
```

Try Adding this part after web view height ratio

```
"messenger_extensions": "true"
```

The Url Should be WhiteListed before using it in the webview. For making the domain Whitelisted. Refer the Link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/domain-whitelisting/

Answer (score 2):

In order for the webview to work on browser(chrome & rambox messenger tested) you need to set `messenger_extensions` to `true` aside from adding the `webview_height_ratio` field.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, webview only started to work in the last update.

Try to update your Messenger app.

https://messengerblog.com/bots/messenger-platform-1-2-link-ads-to-messenger-enhanced-mobile-websites-payments-and-more/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't have a Messenger app to update: I'm writing the JSON myself so I know it's generating the JSON shown in my question.  It's just that for some reason Facebook appears to be ignoring the `webview_height_ratio` property.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you meant by "I don't have a Messenger app to update", but if I understood you correctly, when you touch the button created from your JSON in the Messenger app, it's leaving the app to open the page with a browser. What I meant is that you should go to Google Play / App Store and update your Messenger.

Comment: Ohhh, I see what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that webview only worked with sizes 'tall' and 'compact', as 'full' would open the default browser on my Android phone. 
I'm not using extensions, but tried setting this option to false and true, but that just made the button not appearing.